# SpreadsheetApp insert a new column with header and formula

Tags: google-sheets

I need to insert a column after 5th column with a header(Average Clicks) also the values in this column must be calculated based on a formula (=E4*F4).
I can insert column after 5th by using this

```
sheet.insertColumns(5, 1);
```

Is it possible to create with header and also need to set the formula.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ArrayFormula function to fill the formula into multiple rows.

```
function insertColumns() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(6).getRange(1, 7).setValue("Average Clicks");
  sheet.getRange(2,7).setFormula("=ArrayFormula(E2:E*F2:F)");
}
```